# Using performance point for web usage on demand analysis?

Tags: performancepoint

My customer want to give its functionnal administrators the ability to create custom reports (owner of site can target his site only).

Is there a way to mix the web analytics feature as a gatherer and Performance point service to create inteligent on demand reports ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be. Question is if you are using SP2010 or 2007. If you are using SP2010 then using the BCS or a direct SQL datasource you could query the Usage log database and then use that in your reports.

Comment: there is not SharePoint2010 tag, but it is actually this version. Are you talking about the WSS_logging DB ? If yes, shouldn't this DB supposed to be a black box, not intended to be call directly ?

Comment: I think it;s the web analytics / logging db yes, This the only database you can access directly. MS was even going to publish or has published the schema for it.